# Apps Script making table in doc - Can't set column widths (Child index Error)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-docs

I have build some quote to generate a sales quote, I have successfully added all the items into the quote using a Google Doc template. One issue I am getting is when trying to style the table, I keep getting this error when I have the setColumnWidth added in

[image]

The table is being populated from a mult-dymentional array, works if the setColumnWidth isn't there

[image]

```
var developerTableArray = quoteItem.developerItems;

var devloperTableSection = body.findText("{devloperTable}");
var devloperElement = devloperTableSection.getElement();

var childIndexDevloper = body.getChildIndex(devloperElement.getParent());

body.getChild(childIndexDevloper).asText().setText('');
body.insertTable(childIndexDevloper,developerTableArray).setColumnWidth(1, 60);
```

This is the code I am using to add the table in, am I just doing something wrong? Any help would be so appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setcolumnwidthcolumnindex,-width) `setColumnWidth` takes two parameters: the first is `columnIndex` - the index of the column.

Index `1` refers to the second column of the table. It seems however that your table contains less than 2 columns which is throwing the error.

I recommend you to have a look at the contents of `developerTableArray` to see where the problem lies.

Comment: You Legend! Didn't think to check the array, I was removing a header elements from the table was left the first-row blank so wasn't giving more than one column. Added them back and working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to set the column width for a new table inserted in place of some place holder.

```
function addTable() {
  try {
    let data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let element = body.findText("{devloperTable}").getElement()
    let parent = element.getParent();
    let index = body.getChildIndex(parent);
    let table = body.insertTable(index,data);
    table.setColumnWidth(1,60);
    element.removeFromParent();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

[image]

References

- [Body.findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String))
- [RangeElement.getElement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getElement())
- [Element.getParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#getParent())
- [Body.getChildIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChildIndex(Element))